# How to lower the viewport in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
```

I have got the tags above on my page. What I struggle to achieve is to put the viewport below the black status bar that iphone has got. I read this:

> If content is set to default, the status bar appears normal. If set to black, the status bar has a black background. If set to black-translucent, the status bar is black and translucent. If set to default or black, the web content is displayed below the status bar. If set to black-translucent, the web content is displayed on the entire screen, partially obscured by the status bar.

But I did follow the guidelines, and still dont understand..why there is an overlap between the status bar and the viewport.. I want the viewport to go below the iphone status bar.. how to achieve so?

This solution doesnt also work:

```
  function fullScreen() {
       window.moveTo(0, 1);
      window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
    }
```

An alternative solution could be to resize the document by 5px (shrink it) and give 
 at the beginning of the body. But does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a messy solution, but you could just set the top margin to the size of the status bar.

Comment: I set a br , and it worked..but it isnt the solution I was looking for. It is impossible to manipulate the status bar with css!